# Adding additional html pages beyond index in azure web app.

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I created a web app on Azure.  I am having issues adding additional html pages beyond an index.  Is there something I'm missing? I've been searching to no avail.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. How did you get your index page to the web app: Git? You should be able to just add additional content to your repo, which then gets pushed to your web app.

Comment: I am using kudo and also tried to with the App Service Editor. I have all the pages already in a folder but when I add them to deploy through kudo and attempt to access the website I get a message "You do not have permission to view this directory or page.". If I just add the index, the index works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to define your own start page name for the web app.

Files added to root path(aka wwwroot folder in kudu) can't be accessed with `https://webappname.azurewebsites.net` unless you set [Default document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure#default-documents) in Application settings. Just add your file name in the list. The first matching file in the list is used.

[image]

If your page is deployed to a folder under root path, you also need to set Virtual applications and directories(also in Application settings). Change the physical path value from `site\wwwroot` to `site\wwwroot\foldername`.

[image]